# Trying to make this code with subprocess.check_output python interpreter agnostic

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess, python-2.x

I'm trying to run this code for multiple python interpreter version. I'm getting an error for python3+. 
I would like to know if it is possible to run this piece of code for both python interpreter versions.

```py
output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-la'], **(dict() if sys.version_info[0] < 3 else dict(text=True)))
if sys.version_info < (3, 0):
    output = output.decode()
```

Works fine for python 2.x. But, for python3.x it output the fallowing error:

```py
File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 356, in check_output **kwargs).stdout
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 423, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
```

Comment: Changed in version 3.7: Added the text parameter, as a more understandable alias of universal_newlines. Added the capture_output parameter. Means that "text" parameter is only available in 3.7

Comment: Thanks Jean! I have checked that and it's correct. Something like **(dict(text=True) if sys.version_info > (3, 6) else dict()) should work.

Comment: yes, but there's a simpler approach see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"text" parameter is only available in version 3.7. Which means that your code will fail on an older python 3 version.

If you want to make it run on most versions, it's better to just forget about this, and use `decode` if you're using python 3. I like to use `bytes is not str` to check for this. But you can use a version check as well.

```
output = subprocess.check_output(['ls', '-la'])
if bytes is not str:
    output = output.decode()
```

you need to decode output because `check_output` returns a `bytes` object, which needs decoding in python 3 if you want it to be a `str`.

Decoding with python 2 would work but would return a `unicode` object. The above method guarantees to produce a `str` object whatever the version.

Comment: Indeed a simpler approach for this problem. Thanks Jean!